# Using multicase regex with sed on jenkins

Tags: regex, bash, sed, jenkins

OK, so I'm making a choice parameterized Jenkins job. The choices for the parameters are `DEV` `STAGING` `QA` and `PROD` and they are stored in `${ENV}`

I need to change the variable `${ENV}` to match a string in a URL. I'm trying to do this with a sed command using regex. Is it possible?

I tested `PROD|ING|(?<!Q)A` as the regex in Expresso, and it finds the necessary portions, (`A`,`ING`,`PROD`) which would leave me with either `DEV` `QA` `STG` or `` as my variable value if I replaced them with '', then I'll add something onto the end of it.

When I try to run `echo "DEVSTAGINGQAPROD" | sed "s/PROD|ING|(?<!Q)A//g"` to remove those chars on CentOS it returns `-bash: !Q: event not found`. I want it to return `DEVSTGQA`

`echo "DEVSTAGINGQAPROD" | sed "s/PROD|ING//g` returns `DEVSTAGQA` as it should. The problem I seem to be having is the look behind, to only remove the A if it doesn't have a Q before it.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One problem here is that sed doesn't understand negative lookbehind. Another is your choice of quotes. History expansion is enabled by default in the shell, so `!` has a special meaning and must be escaped inside double quotes.

To deal with the first problem, I'd suggest using Perl instead of sed, as it has a much more advanced regular expression engine. For the second, just use single quotes, within which the `!` will be interpreted literally:

```
$ echo "DEVSTAGINGQAPROD" | perl -pe 's/PROD|ING|(?<!Q)A//g'
DEVSTGQA
```